# 'Google/Analytics.h' file not found - XCode 7

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, ios9, xcode7, google-analytics-sdk

I am having much trouble integrating Google Analytics SDK into my iOS project. I am using XCode 7 and targeting iOS 7. Using Swift 2.0. However I can get the sample working ok (not converting to Swift 2.0 though).

I've tried both install via CocoaPods and by copying the files manually from:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sdk-download

When installing via CocoaPods I've tried both

```
pod 'Google/Analytics'
```

,

```
pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
```

and

```
pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'
```

Either case the XCode build fails with error

```
BridgingHeader.h:2:9: 'Google/Analytics.h' file not found

Failed to import bridging header '/Users/jonas.andersson/Projects/MyAppName/MyAppName/Supporting files/BridgingHeader.h'
```

This on row:

```
#import <Google/Analytics.h>
```

I've also tried to add

```
$(SRCROOT)/Pods/GoogleAnalytics
```

and the rest of the suggestions from [Google/Analytics.h file not found when adding to AppDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427084/google-analytics-h-file-not-found-when-adding-to-appdelegate)

**Update**

Using `pod 'GoogleAnalytics'` and then `#import <Google/Analytics.h>` worked better. However then I get the following error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'GGLContext'
```

when I try setup GA from according to Google documentation:

```
var configureError:NSError?
GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
```

Comment: See [a quick solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046676/file-not-found-in-bridging-header-when-importing-objective-c-frameworks-into-s/34046677#34046677)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Solved it by going away from Googles own tutorial and not use `GGLContext` and importing headers directly.

My podfile:

```
platform :ios, ’7.0’
use_frameworks!

pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
```

And `BridgingHeader.h`:

```
#import "GAI.h"
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
```

And setup:

```
let gai = GAI.sharedInstance()
let id = "my-GA-id"
gai.trackerWithTrackingId(id)
gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = true 
gai.logger.logLevel = GAILogLevel.Verbose
```

Also added to `User Header Search Paths`:

```
$(SRCROOT)/Pods/GoogleAnalytics (recursive)
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it worth with Carthage?

Comment: Sorry, don't know.

Answer (score 7):

```
#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAI.h>
```

Instead of:

```
#import <GoogleAnalytics.h>
```

This what worked for me, XCODE9.0.

Comment: THANK YOU! I also had to add `#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAIFields.h>` and `#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAIDictionaryBuilder.h>`.