# App can't import bridging header and find Google/Analytics.h when running in Release Configuration

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics, cocoapods

So I'm trying to set up the debug/release configurations in the app I'm working on. When trying to test the Release configuration, the app won't build. Says: `Can't import bridging header` and `'Google/Analytics.h' file not found`. But this is only when running in release.

Any ideas on what could be the problem?

Comment: Check if in your target's 'Build Settings' > 'Swift Compiler - General' > 'Install Objective-C Compatibility Header' is enabled for both, debug and release. And also check that 'Swift Compiler - General' > 'Objective - C Bridging Header' is set for both.

Comment: @zero is this under Target settings? If so, then yes it is set for both and both are the correct file.

Comment: Have you specified the correct path for bridging header file in Build settings

Comment: @Joe it runs fine in debug mode. So I assumed yes.

Comment: This reply in another thread answered my question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32344373/6186297

Answer (score 1):

Another option you could try replacing the header with these lines:

```
#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAI.h>
#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAIDictionaryBuilder.h>
#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAIFields.h>
```

Found it from their reference sample app: [Google Analytics iOS Quickstart app](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/ios/analytics/AnalyticsExampleSwift/BridgingHeader.h)